# Can't run Play app on heroku

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.0

I deploy a Play 2.2.1 app on Heroku with this following Procfile :

> web: target/universal/stage/bin/{MY-APP-NAME} -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true

And I don't understand, I have always the same error :

> bash: target/universal/stage/bin/{MY-APP-NAME}: No such file or directory

Here my heroku config :

```
JAVA_OPTS:                  -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
PATH:                       .jdk/bin:.sbt_home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
REPO:                       /app/.sbt_home/.ivy2/cache
SBT_OPTS:                   -Xmx384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

I have no idea what to do, anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Replace `{MY-APP-NAME}` with the name of your app.  Eg, if your app is called `foo`, then it should be:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/foo -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -DapplyEvolutions.default=true
```

The name of your app is declared in the `build.sbt` file, eg:

```
name := "foo"
```

Comment: Yeah I know that, I replace the name of my app by {MY-APP-NAME} for the example.

Comment: The problem is that the folder named "universal" doesn't exist.

Comment: When you push to Heroku, what are you seeing?  Do you see this? $ git push heroku master
-----> Play! app detected

Comment: I answer a little bit late sorry. I'm a beginner with Play and I didn't know that Play uses sbt for dependency management, so I put maven with the project and when Heroku detects a pom.xml he believes that's a Java app. I remove Maven and now it's working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi @JamesRoper I tried with all possible way to deploy my play app to heroku, but I was not able to up and running it on Heroku. I tried what you said in your post but still no luck.

Answer (score 2):

run: sbt clean stage

-to create target/universal/stage/bin/{MY-APP-NAME}

check build.sbt to make sure about your application name and modify it in Procfile

and ultimately git push ...

Answer (score 0):

As I had the same issue, I just wanted to share how I solved it.

So if you are using [sub-projects](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTSubProjects) like me, you have to adjust your Procfile. If you have a sub-project called `server` in a folder `server`, your Procfile should look like this :

```
web: server/target/universal/stage/bin/server -Dhttp.port=${PORT}
```